# Compilation error when using generics and @annotation.varargs (type mismatch)

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, scala-java-interop

*// I changed title according to new state of problem. It's current state is described in the last paragraph*

There is a project written in Scala that provides Java API, and there is workaround to let Java's varargs to be used in core written in Scala. It's like this:

```
// Java code:
varargsMethod(arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

It's a method of Scala class `ClassUsingVarargs` that extends Java class `JavaClassUsingVarargs`, where the following workaround is implemented (oversimplified):

```
public class JavaClassUsingVarargs {
    public ArgClass varargsMethod(ArgClass... args) {
        varargsMethod(Arrays.asList(args)); 
    }
    public abstract ArgClass varargsMethod(List<ArgClass> args) {
        doSomething(args);
    }

}
```

And in core (Scala) it's extended and actions are performed on converted `List` of varargs. This one-more-layer seems unnatural and redundant to me, but I can't come to better idea. The basic problem is that if i write (directly in Scala) `varargsMethod(x: ArgClass*)`, it's type is `Seq`, but from Java API comes `Array`/`List`.

Is there any intuitive way that's more convenient that this?

*Important update*

I've found out about `@annotation.varargs`, but the problem is my methods are generics, and when I add that annotation, I get compilation error:

```
[error] (core/compile:compile) scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeError: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[my.api.java.MyParametrizedType[(some other)T(in method doSmth)]]
[error]  required: Seq[my.api.java.MyParametrizedType[T(in method doSmth)]]
[error] Total time: 13 s, completed Aug 6, 2013 7:16:26 PM
```

What's that?

Comment: Where does the type mismatch error happens? Please post the full code.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, https://github.com/mesos/spark/tree/scala-2.10/core/src/main/scala/spark/api/java. There are two files:  `JavaSparkContext.scala` which extends `JavaSparkContextVarargsWorkaround.java`. I'd like to use @annotation.varargs to get rid of all the java interlayers. I've tried this approach on simple cases and it performs well. Made this minimal example for you to show the general idea. Notice that I removed `extends ...` part in class declaration and, of course, `override`s too: https://gist.github.com/cdshines/6175252. (Line 243) Log: https://gist.github.com/cdshines/6175272.